# Can we create an Angular project using an existing Typescript project?

Tags: angular, typescript

Are there any tools or a processes to import a typescript project into a new Angular application? Or create an Angular application using an existing Typescript project.

I wanted to use an example typescript project like this https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/tree/master/examples/typescript

Comment: You might want to reformulate your question a bit, it doesn't really make sense the way you ask it.

Comment: Not sure why a '-1`. I was looking at any options/tools that we can use to create an Angular project using an existing Typescript project. The dropbox was an example. I'm updating my question.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you to reformulate the question. Someone didn't quite understand it, and downvoted you. I made an assumption in my answer, and now I'm not sure it actually answers your question.

Saying things like "import a typescript project" has an ambiguous meaning that can be interpreted in many different ways. At first I thought you just wanted to know how you can import the dropbox SDK into your angular project. On second thought it looks like you actually want the examples. See what I mean?

Comment: Also, some people might downvote you just because you haven't mentioned what you tried, nor provided any code that you wrote which might help clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to create an Angular application that uses the Dropbox JS SDK, that looks relatively easy.

Just run in your application folder:

```
npm install dropbox
```

The dropbox npm package comes along with typescript typings, so you can use the SDK in whatever typescript project you want, not just Angular ones.

Once that completes, in your service (component? - hopefully not) ts file:

```
import { Dropbox } from 'dropbox';
...
let dbx: Dropbox = new Dropbox({accessToken: ''});
```

And once you have that Dropbox instance, you can probably do whatever you need.